# Listview recycler applying last hidden view width on new visible row

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I am using listview viewHolder pattern to render listview rows. Each row contains a 2 vertical textview with background.
I added a animation on last added view. The animation changes the width of row from parent width to wrap_content. Now the problem is when I am scrolling and as soon as last row hides and first hidden view appear, the new view width is equal to last hidden view.

I think it's because listview recycler is recycling last hidden view and giving to new visible view but how do I adjust width to wrap content instead of last visible view width.

This is listview row xml layout

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/contentWithBackground"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:paddingLeft="25dp"
        android:paddingRight="25dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtMessage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:background="@null"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:autoLink="all"
            android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="3dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:maxWidth="250dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtInfo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:textSize="9sp"
            android:textColor="#802B2B2B" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout> 


public static class ViewHolder {
        public TextView txtMessage;
        public TextView txtInfo;
        public LinearLayout content;
        public LinearLayout contentWithBG;
    }

    private ViewHolder createViewHolder(View v) {

        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.txtMessage = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtMessage);
        holder.content = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.content);
        holder.contentWithBG = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.contentWithBackground);
        holder.txtInfo = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtInfo);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflator.inflate(R.layout.list_item_message, parent, false);
            holder = createViewHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        final TextView msg = holder.txtMessage;
        final View contentBackground = holder.content;
        msg.setText((chatMessage.getMsg()));
        holder.txtInfo.setText(getTimeText(chatMessage));

        //only add animation on last item
        if((position == getCount() -1)){

                TextView text = holder.txtMessage;
                text.measure(0, 0);
                int textWidth = text.getMeasuredWidth();
                AnimationSet animationSet = new AnimationSet(false);
                Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.bottom_up);
                ResizeAnimation a = new ResizeAnimation(text);
                Display mDisplay = context.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
                int width = mDisplay.getWidth();
                width *= 0.75;
                a.setDuration(250);
                a.setParams(width, textWidth);
                a.setStartOffset(150);
                animationSet.addAnimation(anim);
                animationSet.addAnimation(a);
                holder.contentWithBG.startAnimation(animationSet);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To stop recycling of the views from JellyBean onwards you can set the Transient State property of a view to true.
       `view.setHasTransientState(true);`

To use it for the versions before Jellybean i used 
       `ViewCompat.setHasTransientState(view,true);`
Hence you can set this property to your last view and it will not be recycled.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @hars
Please help me in 1 more thing

When I am adding new row to listview,  the old views when go up, there is a flicker. Is there any way I can avoid this flicker

Comment: @user3265443 well probably some answers in flickering case suggest that you would have to clear out previous references from the view if it is getting reused or you can use some animations when you are adding the item in your listview maybe this can help. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1wyhY68esZY